# Combinations of binary values in r

Tags: r, binary, combinations

I am new to R and would like to do some work on combinations of columns. I am struggling to write some code that will count the number of 1's in several combinations of columns. Suppose I have the following columns:

A         B         C         D

I would like to first count the number of 1's in each individual column (A, B, C, D).
Then the number of 1's in every 2-column combination (AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD).
Then the number of 1's in every 3-column combination (ABC, ACD, BCD)
Then the number of 1's in all columns (ABCD)

The actual data frame has about 10 or so columns.

It was suggested to create a binary value for each combination and then have all those binary values in an array, but any advice would be appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: What does it mean to combine binary columns A and B? Compute the OR or AND?

Comment: The OR, calculate all 1's that appear in columns A or B.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure you know what I refer by OR... So just to clarify, if A is (0, 0, 1, 1) and B is (0, 1, 1, 0), what should be the result of combining A and B: 3 or 4?

Comment: 3, all the 1's that appear in either columns A or B.

Comment: So despite the ambiguous wording you are indeed looking for a logical OR. It might be better to say you are looking for the number of rows that contain at least a `1`, as it is not the same as the total number of `1` in your sub matrices. I hope my answer provided you a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sample data:

```
n <- 10
dat <- data.frame(A = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
                  B = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
                  C = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
                  D = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE))
```

A function that given a number of columns to combine, computes all combinations and corresponding sums:

```
count.or <- function(dat, n = 2) {
  or.sum <- function(cols) sum(rowSums(dat[cols]) > 0)
  counts <- combn(colnames(dat), n, FUN = or.sum)
  names  <- combn(colnames(dat), n, FUN = paste, collapse = "")
  setNames(counts, names)
}
```

In action:

```
count.or(dat, 1)
# A B C D 
# 6 6 5 9 
count.or(dat, 2)
# AB AC AD BC BD CD 
#  8  7  9  9 10  9 
count.or(dat, 3)
# ABC ABD ACD BCD 
#   9  10   9  10 
count.or(dat, 4)
# ABCD 
#   10
```

Or in one call:

```
unlist(lapply(1:4, count.or, dat = dat))
#    A    B    C    D   AB   AC   AD   BC   BD   CD  ABC  ABD  ACD  BCD ABCD 
#    6    6    5    9    8    7    9    9   10    9    9   10    9   10   10
```

Comment: Is it possible to return unique combinations only, such that at the end all the combinations add up to 10 in this example?